# How do I refer to a quote whose author I don't know?

Tags: writing-style, plagiarism

I have a quotation from someone which I want to use. But this quotation is from person X, who doesn't remember who said it to him.

1. How do I refer to it in this case?
2. If I don't mention the author, is this plagiarism?

Comment: You can edit and delete the second question, if this is not your concern.

Comment: Questions like this really belong on [Writers.se], they are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

You can write as:

> "quote" - Anonymous

This would indicate that the quote is not yours, it's someone else's but you don't know the name of the person. Yes, it would count as plagiarism if you "lifted" someone else's quote without attributing them. If you don't know the source, mention **Anonymous**. Like it's done [here](http://www.quotes.net/authors/Anonymous).

If it is a website, newspaper article or so, the rules will differ. For example, [this](http://aus.libguides.com/apa/apa-no-author-date) is the Chicago style guide for citing works of unknown persons/sources. [Purdue Owl Writing](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/03/) also has a few guidelines.